# Iterative insert of a (Atomic) Linked List

Tags: list, rust, linked-list

```
struct Elem {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Arc<Mutex<Elem>>>,
}
```

```
fn insert(elem: &mut Option<Arc<Mutex<Elem>>>, val: i32) {

    match elem {
        None => {
            let tmp = Elem { val, next: None };
            let tmp = Mutex::new(tmp);
            let tmp = Arc::new(tmp);
            *elem = Some(tmp);
        }
        Some(e) => {
            insert(&mut e.lock().unwrap().next, val);
        }
    }
}
```

How to convert this code in an iterative form? The problem I found (with many different method combinations attempts) is that a temporary value is dropped while borrowing

It seems also that rustc compiler won't optimize away tail recursion
https://godbolt.org/z/Ke4srh5d9

I had the same problem using `Rc<RefCell<` instead of `Arc<Mutex<`  and this is an example of not compiling code because `temporary value dropped while borrowed`

```
struct Node {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
}


fn insert_node(node: &mut Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>, val: i32) {
    let mut node = node;
    loop {
        match node {
            None => {
                let tmp = Node { val, next: None };
                let tmp = RefCell::new(tmp);
                let tmp = Rc::new(tmp);
                *node = Some(tmp);
                return;
            }
            Some(e) => {
                node = &mut e.as_ref().borrow_mut().next;
                //unsafe {node = &mut (*e.as_ptr()).next}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, this is a rather unusual implementation. It's much more common for a singly linked list to push at the head, and to use a doubly linked list with pointers to both head and tail if you want to be able to push at both ends. Your implementation of `append()` has linear runtime, while usually this is a constant time operation.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this iteratively in safe code. You need to keep all the lock guards alive, and each lock guard needs to have a scope nested inside that of the previous one to satisfy the borrow checker. This is only possible by using recursion, and implicitly storing the lock guards on the stack. If you want to store the lock guards in, say, a vector instead, you need unsafe code, and you need to make sure that the lock guards are dropped in reverse order manually.

Comment: @SvenMarnach i had the same problem with `Rc<RefCell<`, up to now, it gives me problems with temporary value dropped, which is the reference to the value that is (also) owned by the head

Comment: Sure, you will have exactly the same problem with `RefCell`s, just with reference wrappers instead of lock guards. From the borrow checker's point of view, they are essentially the same thing. The takeaway probably is that this is a bad way to implement a linked list, linked lists are probably a bad data structure for your use case, and you shouldn't try to [learn Rust with enitrely too many linked lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).